# Embedding resources (images, sound bits, etc) into a Java project then use those resources

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, imagesource

I have searched for a method of embedding a resource in a java project (using Eclipse v3.6.0) then using that embedded resource within a control (e.g., `JLabel`).  I have seen methods of referencing resources from the file system.  Once the project has been developed I would like to publish the application as an executable.  It should be noted these executables will be deployed/launched to Windows, *NIX, and Linux platforms.

I know this can be done in the Visual Studio world, but I'm very unfamiliar how to do this in Java/Eclipse IDE.  As a side question, how do I get Eclipse to create the project as a executable so it can be launched?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Mark*

**UPDATE 1:**

Based upon [BalusC's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721730/98528), I wanted to share the code I have to resolve my problem.  My classes are under the package of "`Viking.Test`" and then I placed the image file under the package "`Viking.Test.Resources`".  This is all done within Eclipse to import the image into the project.

1. I imported the image by right-clicking on the *Project -> Import -> General/File System* for the import source.
2. Selected the folder which contained the image to import
3. Selected "`Project/src/Viking/Test/Resources`" for the *'Into folder'* parameter
4. Didn't change any of the options and clicked *"Finished"*

In the source file I added the following code to insert the image into a `JLabel` (`LblLogo`)

```
try
{
  ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(
    "Viking/Test/Resources/MyImage.jpg");
  Image logo = ImageIO.read(input);
  LblLogo = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( logo ) );
  LblLogo.setBounds(20, 11, 210, 93);
  getContentPane().add(LblLogo);
}
catch ( IOException e ) {  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just put those resources in the source/package structure and use [`ClassLoader#getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain them as `URL` or `InputStream` from the classpath by the full qualified package path.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/image.gif");
// ...
```

Or if it is in the same package as the current class, you can also obtain it as follows:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.gif");
```

---

> As a side question, how do I get Eclipse to create the project as a executable so it can be launched.

*Rightclick Java Project > Export > Runnable JAR File* .

Comment: Thanks BalusC, got it working.  The one strange thing is the Right-Click Java Project -> Export -> Runnable JAR File works on one machine, but not the other.  The machine that is doesn't work on I can issue the command "java -jar MyJarFile.jar" and it will run.  During the exporting, if I select "Package required libraries into generated JAR" I get error message "Could not find the main class. Program will exit".  Need to figure out why and I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Some things have changed since Eclipse 3.5. Which version is running at the machines? Easiest is to execute it once using Ctrl+F11 so that it get saved as last *Run As* configuration which you can pick during the export.

Comment: Okay, at home I was running Java v6 Update 21 and Java v6 Update 20 on the one that didn't work.  I don't see why that would cause any concerns, but I uninstalled Java and re-installed Java.  After I re-installed Java I was able to double-click and the jar file executed.  Cool.  I am not sure what the problem was.  Now the other concern is that even when I close the window an instance of 'javaw.exe' is still running. Boy, I have to get use to this Java thing.  Thanks for all the help BalusC!

Comment: Okay, with regards to fact that an instance of "javaw.exe" was still executing, I discovered that I needed to call the System.exit(0) function as described [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17933.html).