# Java path to support both IDE and generated JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, path, classpath

I have an issue with path names in my code. Let's say I have a main class:

```
com.test.LoadFile.java
```

Similarly I have a `myxml.xml` file under `com.test.` Meaning that the Java file and XML file are under same package.

Can somebody suggest how, when I do (inside LoadFile)

```
File file = new File("???/myxml.xml")
```

What should the path be, to support both:

1. Eclipse IDE code (after including the above code into a single Java project) 
   and
2. Run the main LoadFile class outside of the IDE (in a JAR file)

What should I use as the value of the path variable to include in the generated project JAR?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721706/embedding-resources-images-sound-bits-etc-into-a-java-project-then-use-those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the XML file using getResourceAsStream(), as long as it's in the CLASSPATH:

```
InputStream is = LoadFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/myxml.xml");
```

EDIT: If you are packaging into a .jar, you must specify the complete path of the resource from the jar's root folder using "/" at the beginning of string