# Can't get a image from resources

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have problem to get an image from another package of my Eclipse project! I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721706/embedding-resources-images-sound-bits-etc-into-a-java-project-then-use-those)
My code is this CreateTableOnPDF.java:

```
288    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
289    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("images/sun.png");
290    PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(doc, input);
```

I getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg.setPropertiesFromAWT(PDJpeg.java:132)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg.<init>(PDJpeg.java:113)
at MainClasses.CreateTableOnPDF.main(CreateTableOnPDF.java:290)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong? Maybe is the a lot hour a have spend already infront of my monitor.

Here is my project structure:
[image]

Thanks for your attention and time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the [API](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/xobject/PDJpeg.html#PDJpeg(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument,%20java.io.InputStream)) docs, you should put JPEG data, **not** PNG data.

```
public PDJpeg(PDDocument doc, InputStream is) throws IOException
```

Parameters:

- `doc` - The document to create the image as part of.
- `is` - The **stream** that contains the JPEG data.

Throws:

- `IOException` - If there is an error reading the JPEG data.

Comment: You can use PDPixelMap for PNG files. The second param takes a BufferedImage which you get with ImageIO.read().

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting `input` as `null`? If so try the path as `"../images/sun.png"`

Comment: I am getting the same exception! :(

Comment: Are you sure its the image...Its throwing IllegalStateException not NullPointer

Comment: If a change with this:
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("images/logo.jpg");
It works!

Comment: I just saw what was my mistake! I try to create PDJpeg object with png image! Thanks for your time Dinal.