# Load Image into Java with BufferedImage - Oracle tutorial

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource

I'm a beginner in Java and I would like to load an image with this script:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This class demonstrates how to load an Image from an external file
 */
public class LoadImageApp extends Component {

BufferedImage img;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

public LoadImageApp() {
   try {
       img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/java.png"));//cannot found image
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }

}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (img == null) {
         return new Dimension(100,100);
    } else {
       return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    f.add(new LoadImageApp());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Then I put a picture on a folder resource "resources", change the name of the location of the picture like "/resources/java.png" and when I compile, there is an empty window without image.

You can see error here : https://ibb.co/ysjNyQw

Comment: `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/java.png"))`

Comment: Thanks but , i have got that : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at tst.LoadImageApp.<init>(LoadImageApp.java:54)
 at tst.LoadImageApp.main(LoadImageApp.java:78)

Comment: this is the problem https://ibb.co/ysjNyQw

Comment: Since "resources" is called "Resources", you may need to either rename it or change your code to reflect it. You may also want to read up on "embedded resources", [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721706/embedding-resources-images-sound-bits-etc-into-a-java-project-then-use-those)

Comment: I renamed and replace the code with 'code'public LoadImageApp() {
       try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Resources/java.png");
        // ...
       } finally {
        
       }

    }
'code'   and a empty windows opened without image

Comment: like this : https://ibb.co/9wpb6sd

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you're going to want to do is do some research into "embedded resources", [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721706/embedding-resources-images-sound-bits-etc-into-a-java-project-then-use-those)

I don't use Eclipse, I use Netbeans, but the process should be the same

[image: Project]

As you can see, I've placed my image in the `resources` package within the projects "sources".  This will ensure that it's available at runtime via the class path search mechanism (and embedded within the resulting Jar file when I export it).

I then used a `JLabel` to display it...

[image: Example image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/java.png"));
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(label);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to continue using a custom painting route, I suggest having a read of:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

to get a better understanding of how painting works in Swing and how you should work with it

Comment: Thanks it's working. I just don't understand on the main section why you can lauch the objet without a name like this :  Test c1 = new Test(); I use to do like that and then c1.method . Why new Test() works without variable?

Comment: `new Test()` is calling the classes constructor, see `public Test()`