# Set image background java

Tags: java, image, swing

I started programming in SWING class recently and I try to set Image (like Space) and on it image(like spaceShip) like background. I
would love for you to help me,

Here is my code

```
public class SpaceWar {

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Space War");
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new SpaceWar();
        
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    public SpaceWar() {
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        Dimension size
        = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setPreferredSize(size);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(frame.getPreferredSize().width/4,0,
                frame.getPreferredSize().width/2,frame.getPreferredSize().height);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(new Background());
        spaceShip sp1 = new spaceShip();
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel.add(sp1);

        System.out.println(panel.getPreferredSize().width);

    }
     
          
}   


class spaceShip extends JLabel{
    
    static ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("spaceShip.png");

    public spaceShip(){
    
    sizeIcon(100,100,img);
    setIcon(img);
    
    }
    public static ImageIcon sizeIcon(int w,int h,ImageIcon image1){
        
        Image image = image1.getImage(); // transform it 
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(w,h,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
        ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
        return img1;    
    }
}
class Background extends JPanel{
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) { // paint() method
          super.paint(g);
          ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("space.jpg");
          Image bg = image.getImage();
          g.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);
          
    }
}
```

Comment: frame.setLayout(null); That’s not going to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your "core" problem is the use of `null` layouts and a lack of understand of how components are sized and positioned.  Having said that, if your aim is to make a game, this probably isn't the best approach anyway.

Instead, I'd focus on creating a "surface", onto which you can paint all your assets directly, this will give you much greater control.

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to get a better understanding how the paint system works and how you can work with it to perform custom painting.

I'd also avoid `ImageIcon`, it's not the best way to handle images, instead, take a look at `ImageIO` ([Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)), it will generate an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded and will return a fully realised image (unlike `ImageIcon` which off loads the image loading to a background thread).

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new MainPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage ufo;
        private BufferedImage background;

        private int horizontalPosition = 106;

        public MainPane() throws IOException {
            ufo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/ufo.png"));
            background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/starfield.png"));
            System.out.println("background = " + background);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            paintBackground(g2d);
            paintUFO(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void paintBackground(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
        }

        protected void paintUFO(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int x = (getWidth() - ufo.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - ufo.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(ufo, x, y, this);
        }

    }
}
```

The example makes use of [embedded resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721706/embedding-resources-images-sound-bits-etc-into-a-java-project-then-use-those) (something to read up on).  Managing your assets this way will save you countless hours of wondering why they aren't loading/working.  How you achieve this will come down to your IDE and build system, for example, Netbeans and Eclipse will allow you to add resources directly to the `src` directory, when you're not using maven.

At some point, you're going to want to learn about [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)